# RecyclerView notifyItemChanged call onBindViewHolder also on not visible cells

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a vertical `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayoutManager` with different item types and one `ViewHolder`. It is a messaging screen.

I want show/hide message date on click on the cell.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layout = R.layout.xxx
        val viewHolder = ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layout, parent, false))


        viewHolder.itemView.layout?.setOnClickListener {
            setMessageDateVisibility(viewHolder)
        }

        return viewHolder
    }
```

So i added the method to reload view with `notifyItemChanged(pos)`

```
private fun setMessageDateVisibility(holder: ViewHolder) {
        val pos = holder.adapterPosition
        if (pos.toLong() == THREAD_DEFAULT_POSITION)
            return

        val message = mDataset[pos]

        message.isDateVisible = !message.isDateVisible
        notifyItemChanged(pos)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val message = mDataset[position]

        itemView.message_date.text = message.date
        itemView.message_date.visibility = if (message.isDateVisible)
            View.VISIBLE
        else
            View.GONE
    }
```

But the problem a the end, is that because of this line `notifyItemChanged(pos)`, the override `onBindViewHolder` method called for all not visible cells and so my screen is lagging with 150/200 cells

Can you help me to find a solution ?

Comment: have you tried removing notifyItemChanged ?

Comment: @Vikas yes i tried to remove notifyItemChanged, any view are called but the visibility of the date view doesn't change

Comment: try setting the on click listener inside the onBindViewHolder.

Comment: In `onBindViewHolder` why do you use `holder.layoutPosition` instead of `position` parameter for `mDataset[pos]`?

Comment: @shinwan good question, i used to this i think

Comment: @Vikas yes i tried and this is the same

Comment: `layoutPosition` won't directly translate to item position you modify in `setMessageDateVisibility` (there you use `adapterPosition` which is correct). Most likely that's the culprit.

Comment: @shinwan humm i changed it for `onBindViewHolder` and this is the same

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Do you mind to update your question with your latest change? From existing state, I would change the code in `onBindViewHolder(…)` with `val message = mDataset[position]` and remove `val pos = holder.layoutPosition`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200297/discussion-between-remy-and-shinwan).